# How to reduce output of javac ant task?

Tags: java, ant, javac

My javac task keeps output thousand of these lines:

```
[javac] AClass.java omitted as AClass.class is up to date.
```

How can i reduce these lines from output stream or move them to a single file?

Comment: Could you show the `<javac>` portion of your Ant script? It's strange that it's saying your java file is up to date (normally it would say the java file is omitted because the class file is up to date). Are your srcdir and destdir are set to the same location?

Comment: sorry my mistake, the output is `AClass.java omitted as AClass.class is up to date.`
srcdir and destdir are different, the task run correctly, the problem is too many output

Comment: In that case, it just sounds like the verbose option is on. Don't include `-v` or `--verbose` in your command and you should be fine.